# How to execute Linux bash command in Apache NiFi in Windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, apache-nifi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use NiFi on Windows 10 machine with installed Linux subsystem (Ubuntu).
My task is to execute bash scripts and commands using NiFi. I tried to use `ExecuteProcess` and `ExecuteStreamCommand` with selected commands like simply '`bash`' or '`bash ls`'  for test purposes, but all I got was:

> ExecuteProcess[id=4f530725-0171-1000-d1b1-7df587eada7e] /bin/ls:
>   /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file

If I try to pass basic Windows commands everything is OK.

Is there a way to run bash commands in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Windows user but according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#bashexe), in order to get to the Linux-style commands you have to run `Bash.exe`, so I'm guessing you'll need to specify `-c` as an argument followed by the Linux bash command you want to run (as a string), something like:

```
bash -c "ls"
```

Comment: Yes it works in Win10, but in NiFI in *ExecuteProcess* I have to pass it to **Command Arguments** in next way: `c;"ls`

Comment: As well I found out that we can pass .sh scripts to **Command Arguments**. It was not clear mentioned in docs.